# Qt/Pyside: strange indexes in QtCore.QAbstractItemModel

Tags: qt, pyside

I have a subclass of the QtCore.QAbstractItemModel to create a tree view. This works most of the time but sometimes index.internalPointer() returns an object of a class that should not be in there. I overrid createIndex() to see what indexes are created, but all calls to createIndex() have the correct input.

My question is: where are indexes for the QtCore.QAbstractItemModel created, besides by calling createIndex.

I am using Qt 4.8 and a very recent version of Pyside.

Cheers, Lars

PS: i have been searching for a day now and i am starting to suspect a bug in qt/pyside.

Comment: Do you keep indexes somewhere between different events?

Comment: indexes are invalidated when the model changes, use QPersistentModelIndexes if you want them to remain valid

Comment: i don't keep or need to keep indexes, it's just that all calls to createIndex have the correct input (which i check by overriding createIndex and checking the input values and then calling the super implementation, nothing else), but somehow Qt calls QAbstractItemModel.parent(index) from beginRemoveRows() and at that point index.internalPointer() has a value that never passed through createIndex(), so i concluded that indexes must also be created somewhere else. The model only changes after beginRemoveRows().